# Can a Library jar read properties from Spring Cloud Config Server?

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-cloud

I have a shared Library that needs some properties from a .properties file. This shared Library will be used by a Spring Boot application. We already have a Spring Cloud Config server which is serving the properties to this Spring Boot application.

Now, we want the properties for the Library also to be fetched from the Config Server, rather than packaging it's properties file along with the library jar file.

***Can I let my Library file pick-up properties from the Spring Cloud Config server ? The Spring Cloud Config server documentation states the following.. seeing it, looks like only a 'Spring Boot' application can talk to the Spring Cloud Config Server to fetch properties from there.***

Any pointers or suggestions ?

> can be used with any application running in any language
>
> To use these features in an application, just build it as a Spring
>   Boot application that depends on spring-cloud-config-client

Ref: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a Library cannot talk to the Spring Cloud Config Server to get the properties file. Instead the config server should have those Library file's properties define din the using application's properties file.

Library: x.jar
Application: y.jar

Property file in Config Server: y.properties / y.yml

This property file will have the properties for classes present both in x.jar and in y.jar

Comment: The spring cloud config server serves up the properties on an HTTP endpoint (authenticated if required).  It returns JSON following a simple URL/endpoint protocol - there's no reason why you couldn't write your own library with an HttpClient to access the config server and use those retrieved properties as you see fit (for client apps that are not Spring-Boot based).  I dont know of an existing library but I have a similar need now to access centralized configuration/properties from a non-Spring application.